# Difference between "cloning" a request and "replaying" a request?

Tags: fiddler

I'm new to Fiddler and have run across something that seems strange to me. If I select an entry and then click Replay, I get different behavior from when I drag an entry into the Composer window and click Execute.

Should the different behavior between these two methods of re-making a request be different?

Note: I called the second method "cloning" a request because the Composer window says "You can clone a prior request by dragging and dropping a session from the Web Sessions list)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "different behavior" specifically?

The two operations you describe *should* behave the same way unless the server returns a redirect or an authentication challenge, in which case preferences will control whether Fiddler automatically authenticates and/or follows the redirect.

Please feel free to email me (Help > Send Feedback) details and/or screenshots of the difference you see.

Comment: Yes, the server was returning a 302 redirect and Fiddler only make another request to the new location when I dragged the entry into the Composer window (cloning it). When I just clicked Replay, Fiddler did not follow the redirect.

Comment: In the QuickExec box beneath the session list, you can execute `prefs set fiddler.reissue.autoredircount 10` to configure the Reissue command to chase up to 10 redirects.